# Problems with on submit and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, onsubmit

Working on a project where form changes are checked for. I'm having difficulty removing the changes have been made alert when the user submits the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    changes_made = false;

    $('input, select, textarea').on('change', function() {
        changes_made = true;
    });

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        if(changes_made) { return 'You have made changes on this page.'; }
    });

    $('form').each(function() {
        $(this).on('submit', function() {
            changes_made = false; 
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: So what's your question? Also, 1) the code you posted doesn't attempt to 'remove' (by which I assume you mean 'undo') any changes made to the form - it simply seems to attempt to track the changes themselves; 2) the change event does not fire on textual inputs, only on inputs where you switch between pre-set values (selects, checkboxes etc); 3) your beforeunload event handler returns a value, but nothing will receive this return value. Presumably you meant to cancel the event, and then convey this message to the user.

Comment: Ignoring the textarea problem i'm attempting to loop through each form on a page and set the variable changes_made to false - alternative would be to remove the beforeunload in the same place.

Comment: not able to reproduce the issue.. see http://jsfiddle.net/J9nJe/4/, try to refresh the page and see your console nothing happens enter smthing and then refresh and you will see the message logged in console..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to revert any changes the user has made, you need to store the original contents of the form. That way, instead of waiting for change events, you can just compare the old form contents to the new contents, and replace if necessary.

Other tidbits: you need a `var` before your variable declaration (otherwise the variable ends up attached to the window object). And unless your form submit is an ajax call, there is no point in setting changes_made back to false. The page will reload and changes_made will be false again anyway.

Comment: Attempting to alert the user changes have been made and prompting them to save before leaving the page. I'm using changes_made = false to prevent the prompt from coming. I could also use .off to remove it but either way it doesn't seem to ever fire the form.submit()

Comment: The following does not work - looking for the correct way to do this     
$('form').each(function() {
        $(this).on('submit', function() {
            changes_made = false; 
        });
    });